# How to change laravel orm to my query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have change following my query in laravel orm. But it's not work.

in sql

```
select * from `promotions` join items on items.id = promotions.item_id where promotions.start >= "2014-12-30" and promotions.end <="2015-01-30"
```

in orm

```
$result = Promotion::whereNull('promotions.deleted_at')
                ->select('promotions.*','items.name as i_name')
                ->join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'promotions.item_id')
                ->where('start', '>=', $start || 'end', '<=', $end)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Chain two `where` calls:

```
->where('start', '>=', $start)
->where('end', '<=', $end)
```

Or use `whereBetween`.

Comment: I also use both. it's not ok first. but second whereBetween is ok however i have 2 parameters start and end <= fields. what shoud I do?